# How can I get all the information about an ID using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a question using Ajax call, I have this code below :

```
$.ajax({
  async: true,
  url: 'test/',
  type: 'POST',
  datatype: 'text json',
  data: {
    id: id,
  },
  success: function(data) {
    // Get the data of the id (1)
  },
  error: function(xhr, errmsg, err) {

  }
});
```

And I would like to do a query which allows to get all the information with the ID in data there is the id and I think I have to write the information to get the data of the id at (1). But I don't know how doing this, could you help me please?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you elaborate it more. Because answer of this question is totally depends what you get from the ajax. So that further you could parse the data.

Comment: If you're posting the ID to the back-end, wouldn't the data that is returned pertain only to that ID, i.e. just the `data` itself? In any case, without knowing what `data` is, we can't really help at all.

Answer (score 0):

You did't attached example of returning data

if it's array of objects and you need the first one you can use
`var firstObj = data[0];`

If your object has Id field you should use filter to find it

```
firstObj = data.filter(function (item)
    {
        return item.ID == 1 //if true object will be pushed to returned array
    })[0]; //get only first (and I assume unique) result
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if you want all information related to a particular id then you can go with form  
$("form").serialize(); for example 

<form id="myForm">

//mention components text,radio,etc between this form tag
</form>

and finally when control goes to ajax call,then your code should be

$.ajax({
async: true,
url: 'test/',
type: 'POST',
datatype: 'text json',
data:$('#myForm').serialize(),
success: function(data) {
},
error: function(xhr, errmsg, err) {
}
});

through this approach your all data will be in data attribute.
let me know if it works for you.
```